# Can any on tell me what this XML file Does? Worried its somekind of SpyWare

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generated by octalforty Exile 1.7-->
<!--Copyright (C) 2004 octalforty studios. All rights reserved.-->
<configuration>
    <configurationGeneral showPassword="1" maintainFileAssociations="1" enableHotKeys="1" minimizeToTray="1"/>
    <configurationStorage createBackup="0" autoSave="0" shellOpenReadOnly="0" reloadLastStorage="1" lastStorage="C:\Users\me\Desktop\OctilePasswordfile.pws" reloadReadOnly="0"/>
    <configurationSmartType smartType="0" smartTypeModifier="0" smartTypeVKey="0"/>
    <configurationSorting autoSort="0" autoSortOrder="1"/>
    <configurationClipboard eraseClipboard="0" eraseClipboardTimeout="0"/>
    <configurationPasswordGenerator decimalDigits="0" lowercaseCharacters="0" punctuationMarks="0" specialCharacters="0" uppercaseCharacters="0" passwordLength="0"/>
    <configurationHashGenerator hashOptions="0"/>
    <configurationExportToXml exportFlags="0" exportFileName=""/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: the XML file is not showing up. Can you copy/paste it in here? Or else link everyone to a pastebin

Comment: Next time, to have code show up, indent the line it appears on by four (4) spaces.

Comment: Or select it and click the 101010 (code) button.

Answer (score 6):

Googling `octalforty Exile 1.7` shows that it is a Password Manager. This file appears to be a general configuration file (probably in the AppData folder or the program folder). You appear to have last used Exile to open the file `C:\Users\me\Desktop\OctilePasswordfile.pws`, presumably a password file.

Comment: Yes! Now, go open the file and see what's in there! :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think an XML file can be spyware on its own. This file looks like a configuration file for some program named `octalforty Exile 1.7`. Made by `octalforty studios`. It's possible that this Exile app is spyware, but there's really not enough to make a decision here.

Comment: Octalforty Exile is an open-source password manager, definitely not spyware.

Answer (score 2):

XML files are just used to store information in a particular format.  I can't think of any instance where an XML file itself could be spyware; it's just a text file.  At worst an XML file (like any text file) could be used to store information harvested by spyware.  In this case it looks pretty benign.  Octalforty Exile is an open-source (free) password manager available from [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/Exile.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML

XML files are used by a lot of programs to store data that applies to things like configuration and database type information.

Comment: -1 He didn't ask for a definition on what XML is.

Comment: he did actually it was edited, also i didnt give you the minus one on the comment someone else did